# Entity Reference field in custom line item missing multiple field values

Tags: entities, commerce

I added an entity reference field to a line item within commerce.

Target is user, entity selection is done through a custom view. The view populates the values of a date field within the actual user entity. The preview works as desired, the field has 3 values and those 3 get shown in the views preview.

However looking at the add to cart form it always shows just the last value of this multiple value field. Why are not shown all 3 values in the add to cart form?

Comment: Could it be that the custom products module expects various users to choose from instead of various field values from one single user?

Answer (score 0):

Line-item entity reference fields being displayed as views is most likely not supported, or not very well supported, because it's a very edge-case situation. Nothing appears to be in the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_custom_product) regarding this limitation, so you might make a feature request and see where it goes.